# Partially Checking-in changes in TFS/VSTS2010

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to easily facilitate checking-in in chunks rather than as a whole?
It becomes too much work to create shelvesets for each chunk of check-in. Plus, this is especially a problem with csproj files which are hard to modify manually for each changeset I want to check in. PS: I don't live in an ideal world where I only work on one problem at a time.

Optimally, I would like to be given the option to use the conflict-resolution tool with each check-in, but I couldn't find a way to do this.  Am I the only one with this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: When you say chunk, do you mean "part of a file" or "a file in your current list of checked out files"?

Comment: I don't understand your workflow - what are you trying to accomplish exactly?  Why is using shelvesets too much work?

Answer (score 0):

In Dev11, we have introduced a new concept of My Work, where you can easily switch to different tasks. When you start working, just do as you are used to do with editing files. When you want to work on something else, you can just suspend the work (which will create a shelveset on the background) and you can work on the other problem. Once you are done with the other task, you can resume your suspended work. It will unshelve the changes and even reloads the settings (open windows / breakpoints).

To learn more about My Work see [\\BUILD\ session of Jamie Cool](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-811T)